# cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle Mac

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have cx_Oracle installed and I can successfully import it. But when I try to establish an Oracle connection, I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle`

My operating system is MacOSX, and my ORACLE_HOME is pointing to instantclient_11_2.

Answer (score 3):

First thing first.

Check if your cx_oracle is built for the exactly same version as your Oracle client.

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.clientversion()
```

This should return the version it's expecting to find.

If the versions differ, you should rebuild it against the correctly version.

Comment: I got (11, 2, 0, 3, 0), which is the correct version.

Comment: @rijo-simon Ok, Did you tried any of related questions for solution ?

Comment: Yes, tried almost all of them. None of the solutions provided a resolution.

Comment: Which version of cx_oracle you're using ? Some earlier version had some problems detecting the InstantClient. Also which method did you use to install it ?

Comment: This is the method I used: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2012/cs327/cx_mac.html

Comment: the cx_oracle version used is 5.3

Comment: Sorry for the delay. On MacOSX it's seen like it's install both 32 and 64 version of python, can you force python to run in [64 bits](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html), if that don't work try to run setup.py again with this workaround on.

Comment: Forcing to run 64 bits python, doesn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For instant client, do not set ORACLE_HOME. Instead follow these instructions:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir -p lib
cd lib
cp /the/location/to/instantclient_11_2/*dylib* .
ln -s libclntsh.dylib.11.1 libclntsh.dylib
```

If you are able to use Instant Client 12.1 things are a bit simpler

```
cd $HOME
mkdir -p lib
cd lib
ln -s /the/location/to/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
```

If you also download and extract the SQL*Plus package you can verify that your client installation is working properly.

Comment: I did the above steps, and it didn't help. What should ORACLE_HOME be in this case?

Comment: ORACLE_HOME should not bet set at all.

Comment: Unsetting ORACLE_HOME didn't help. The issue remains.

Comment: Looks like Instant Client 11.2 on macOS doesn't behave the same way as Instant Client 12.1 on macOS. I have updated the instructions accordingly and verified that it works -- at least for me!

Comment: Did the changes I suggested help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried fixing how you were connecting?  It sounds like you set it up correctly.

Please try the following (fill in your own information):

```
ip_addr = 'ip address'
port = 1521
sid = 'sid'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip_addr, port, sid)
db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', dsn_tns)
```

If that doesn't work, please make sure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly.

Comment: It works with "localhost", loopback, and public ip, still it doesn't work with django. :-(

Comment: If it works with everything but django, it might be a permission issue with whatever port django is using.

Comment: I get this issue when I run gunicorn via supervisord, but it works when I run gunicorn manually on terminal.

Comment: I don't know what gunicorn or supervisord are, but supervisord probably lacks the proper permissions.  You might want to check what user supervisord runs as and check the permissions for that user.

Comment: It did not work with root user in supervisor config also.